# Selecting a user by ID doesn't work, but works by email

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to access some events in my company's Azure AD Outlook.

The problem I am now having is that I can not access the CalendarView (or really I can't access the user at all) when I try to specify the user with an UUID instead of an email. The strange thing is that email works just fine, but I am not allowed to store emails outside of the Azure AD, so ID would be the preferred method.

Here is the exact API call I try to make: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
But all examples only use the `.Me` accessor and not the `.Users[{ID | userPrincipalName}]`

I am quite sure that the UUID I use is correct since it comes from an API call earlier. Or does the documentation article mean something else than the user UUID by `{ID | userPrincipalName}`?

A room looks like this (when read as a JSON object):

```
{
 "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
 "emailAdress": "room@company"
 ...
}
```

This works:

```
await graphClient.Users["room@company"].CalendarView.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

While this does not work:

```
await graphClient.Users["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"].CalendarView.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

When using the UUID I get (IDs not shown here):

```
Code: ErrorInvalidUser
Message: The requested user '<UUID>' is invalid
ClientRequestId: <some ID>
```

I did test this with a hardcoded room id and email but also with the ID object I get from calling the roomlist in C#.
Another inconsistency I encountered is that I can read the whole list of microsoft.graph.room via a http request but not using the C# Microsoft.Graph.Auth package. Reading the data of a room I know the email from does however work.

So does this just not work and the doc doesn't say so?
Does the Microsoft.Graph.Auth package not support those kind of requests?
Or do I use a wrong ID?

Saladino

Comment: Outlook is using an Email address.  The code needs a application with a Calendar which is part of Outlook.  Where would the Calendar come from if you are using a UUID?  Do you have a CalendarGroup configured in Outlook?

Comment: I call the Graph-API to get a list of relevant rooms (places of type microsoft.graph.location) and then try to find all events in a given time that take place there. From a given room I get an email associated to this room and I can find all events with it, but when I use the "id" of the room it seems to not exist at all.

Comment: I would use ID, not the UUID for the API calls; you may want to test the UUID with Microsoft Graph Explorer to see if it works for the user or not..

Comment: In addition, I would try the following: (1) See the user exists in the AAD/M365 (2) Does the issue happens only when you call from your application or from Microsoft Graph Explorer (try the above user who gets error and see if he can able to make Graph API call or not) as well? This will help you to isolate the issue. (3) If you still see the issue from your application, its worth checking which userinfo is passed with the API call and check the token as well using https://jwt.ms

Comment: I meant the uniqueId property of the microsoft.graph.location object I already got. It is in the UUID format, but only called uniqueId.

Comment: I can not use the Graph Explorer since my user account does not have the permissions. I can only test with a client id (now called application id) & secret using OAuth2 flow.

Comment: @Dev (1) The user does exist, since I do retrieve it from the AAD only to read its "id" or "email" property. (3) My test works fine when I use `graphClient.Users["some email"].CalendarView` instead of `graphClient.Users["some id"].CalendarView`

Comment: As you have the clientid, secret you can test it using POSTMAN (you can configure the workflow) as well to isolate the issue. Not sure you tried it?

Comment: Do the rooms all have calendars?

Comment: @jdweng that I am not sure, but my test room does for sure have one, since I can access it via the email. But if they don't have a calendar I should not get the ErrorInvalidUser but a different one, or not?

Comment: Normally an issue like this I would enumerate through the rooms and make a table of rooms, ids, and calendars.  You may have a room and a calendar but you may not have permission to read the calendar and that is why you get an error Invalid User.

Comment: Since I try to access the SAME calendar of the SAME room with 2 different methods and one works and the other does not do you really think this could be a permission problem? As I see it I got the permission 'Calendars.Read' for all rooms and there isn't a permission for i.e. 'Calendars.Read.WithId' or anything other than 'Calendars.Read'

Comment: Could you please console the uuid of user in your code and check if its format is correct and also user hardcode uuid in the code `graphClient.Users["uuid"].CalendarView` to test.

Comment: I edited my question to include this @HuryShen

Answer (score 1):

According to some test, only when I use incorrect object id of user it shows same error message as yours.

If I use another user's object id(not object id of the user do authentication), it will show `ErrorAccessDenied` because do not have permission.

If I use the object id which the user not exist in Azure AD(incorrect object id), it will show same error message with yours. **So please check if the** `uuid` **which you mentioned is the user's object id(shown in below screenshot) in your Azure AD and please check if you input the correct format of object id in your code by** `Console.WriteLine(object id)`
[image]

Comment: Did you test using http requests or using the C# library? I feel like the library is not working correctly (Microsoft.Graph.Auth, it is still in preview but the doc doesn't mention this)

Comment: Hi @Saladino I test both http request and C# library, they all work fine. Could you please go to your azure ad on azure portal and find the user, check if the user with the specified email address you used has same object id with the `uuid` you mentioned.

Comment: @Saladino I guess the `uuid` you used in your code is not same with the user's object id in ad.

Comment: I will have to escalate this to our AAD administrator since I can not access the AAD in any other way than with an app provided with the client ID and secret. But even if this would be the wrong ID I have no idear where I could get the right one, since this is the only ID I get when requesting the room data. This application should work dynamically so hardcoding a list of IDs is not what I want.

Comment: @Saladino Ok, please escalate to your AAD administrator and check if the object id of user is same to `uuid`. And if you want to get the object id of the user, since you have the user's email, you can get all of the user's info by graph [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}`. The object id of user should be `id` field of the response of this api.

Comment: I did edit my question with this already, I am using the `id` field of this response and it does not work, that is whole point of my confusion. I am not allowed to store email adresses outside of the AAD so I am encouraged to use ids.

Comment: @Saladino By the way, may I know which grant flow did you use to do authentication ? username/password flow or client credential flow ?

Comment: Client credentials flow (application ID, tennant ID and client secret) since this is a deamon application.

Comment: Hi @Saladino have you got a chance to check if the two ids are same or different ?